# check specific value in matrix : Lua

Tags: arrays, matrix, lua

i created a randomized 6x6 matrix and was wondering how I would be able to identify and check a specific value in a row and column for example gameboard[1][6] = {} how would I check what's in the brackets.

```
local totalRows= 6
local totalColumns = 6
local gameboard = {}

local function createMatrix()
 for column = 1,totalColumns do
    gameboard[column] = {}
    for row = 1,totalRows do
      gameboard[column][row] = 0
    end
  end
end

local function showMatrix()
  for column = 1,totalColumns do
    for row = 1,totalRows do
      io.write(gameboard[column][row].." ")
    end
    print("\n")
  end
end
```

--is the creation of the matrix

Comment: You're already doing it in `showMatrix`: `gameboard[column][row]`

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not create a randomized matrix as you assign 0 to each element.
You create a 6x6 zero matrix. Hence any element in your matrix is 0. So getting the value of a particular element is not necessary.

As luther already pointed out you already know how to index a field in a 2 dimensional table.

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 3.2 Variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.2):

> ```
>  Square brackets are used to index a table:
>
>   var ::= prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’
> ```

`gameboard[column]` evaluates to a table value for `column` 1 ... 6.

So you can do the same again to index that inner table.

```
local col = gameboard[1]
local val = col[2]
```

or simply `local val = gameboard[1][2]`